# Emitting particles from point x1,y2 to point x2, y2 in Objective C (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, gravity, particles

I'm currently working on an iphone application where there should be "Electrical power flows" visualised from a plug to a device.

I've made this a static line, but it would be way nicer if there was some way that those lines could be replaced by particles, showing an actual flow rather than a simple connection.

So for example device A is at position 100,50 and the plug is at position 200,300. I want particles to start emitting from 200,300 and 'flow' to point 100,50 and stop there.

I've concidered gravity, but as more than 1 device will be in the screen at the same time, this will probably be messed up?

Doing this staticly isn't a solution either: the devices can be moved around the screen and the particles should follow.

EDIT:

In the end a friend of me helped me out:

There is this point X1, y1 and point x2, y2

So to calculate the angle where to go to:
    dx = 100 - 200
    dy = 50 - 300
    speed = 100;
    alpha = arctan2(dy,dx)
    distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    set emittercell litetime = distance / speed
    set emittercell speed = speed
    set emittercel emissionlongitude = alpha

and done!

Comment: Do you need just "some motion" on the connection, or is there always a source and a target, i.e. a directed flow?

Comment: There is always a source and a target So there will always be a "plug" and atleast 1 "device"  (each represented by a uiimage)

Comment: So all particles move in a straight line from the plug to the device? How many particles are you planning to show on screen at the same time? Do the particles move freely or in along a power cord?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to investigate CAEmitterLayer layers.  They should do what you want.  Unfortunately, I've only read about them and never used them and so cannot provide any examples.

[Link to CAEmitterLayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html)